# Lubuntu error Failed to open "%F"

Tags: lubuntu, filemanager, cairo-dock

in lubuntu I installed Cairo dock on desktop,but when I'm going to click on folders or shortcuts I get this error:
Failed to open "%F".
Error when getting information for file '/home/deniz/%F': No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by changing default file manager,
in terminal run this command:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

and in "Utilities" tab, change file manager.

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you see blank files in gedit instead of the file itself - simple solution - go into Preferences and change the %f to "%f"

This will ensure if you have long folder names with spaces in the file path - that it opens it correctly.

Same things for folders - replace %d with "%d"